# Symfony: get existing form reference

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have to reuse some HTML code while migrating a website to symfony. The current HTML page has a form:

```
<form name="n1" id="n1" method="post" onsubmit="return verifSelect()" action="{{path('toto')}}" >

     <select>
         {% for e in experimentations %}
         <option>{{e.name}}</option>
         {% endfor %}
     </select>

</form>
```

I'd like to pass the `Experimentation` object (not only the name) selected to the `toto` page. [The symfony doc uses something like](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions):

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

        return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
}
```

But I have two problems with that:

- How can I get the `form` object reference?
- How can I get the selected `experimentation` object reference (so I can send it as parameter to the next route) ?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: You can't send an object in a request. At least you shouldn't

Comment: Then I can send the experimentation ID, so I can retrieve the full object later. But then the ID will be visible in the HTML page AND I'll have to execute another SQL request. Isn't that dangerous too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand well your problem, but I will try to give you answers :

- You can get the form data's by using $form->getData() in your controller.
- You can't pass the full object as parameter to the next route.

You can do something like that :

```
$data = $form->getData();
return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success',array('experimentation'=> $data['experimentation');
```

then you can get the experimentation id on your totoAction.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: If you don't want to send id's, you can also use slugs or something like that.

Comment: Where does the `$form` comes from? The main issue is that I haven't created the form in a symfony way (it's a static HTML form), so I don't have a `$form` variable. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok so you don't have $form var, use $request->get('experimentation').

Comment: Without the `$form` var, I can't use anything like `$form->isSubmitted()`. How am I supposed to get the choosen experimentation (that's what the `$request->get('experimentation')` is supposed to do right?) before the user even pick one?

Comment: When user submit form, you can get the submitted data's on the Request object ($request). 
`$form->isSubmitted()` is for symfony forms validation, if you don't use symfony form you don't have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to give your select Tag a name so you can reference it `name="experimentations"`. You also would need a submit button, which I guess you have `<input type="submit" value="submit"/>`

```
<form name="n1" id="n1" method="post" onsubmit="return verifSelect()" action="{{path('toto')}}" >

     <select name="experimentations">
         {% for e in experimentations %}
         <option>{{e.name}}</option>
         {% endfor %}
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>
```

To get the Information in the controller class use the `$request`-Object.
function

```
class DefaultController extends Controller {
    /**
     * 
     * Matches /todo/
     * 
     * @Route("/todo/", name="Todo")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
         $experimentations = $request->request->get("experimentations");
         ...
    }
```

As far as I know you can't use the form-Object in this case, but people may correct me...